# Applying URI value to random line from .txt file that's located in internet

Tags: java, android, android-studio, random, uri

How can I apply URI value to a random line from text file that's located in internet? If it helps the solution the program can also access at text file that contains number of total lines in the other text file.

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after lot of brainstorming I came up with a solution. Since I'm novice in Java I suspect this isn't a good solution but at least it works. If you have better solutions I would appreciate you putting here them. After initial testing this code works decent but I'm afraid there might be some issues if the .txt file is large.

**1) Add into imports**

```
import android.os.StrictMode;
```

**2) after setcontentview write:**

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```

**3) Then create activity with this code:**

```
        InputStream fs;
        fs = new URL("http://example.com/file.txt").openStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            array.add(br.readLine());
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(array.size());
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(array.get(randomIndex));
```